# Session Scoped Managed bean is null in ajax request

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, managed-bean

I am using JSF 2 and primefaces 2.1.3 with tomcat. I am trying to access the session scoped managed bean in the converter class in the following way.

```
MemberConverter{
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2)
                throws ConverterException {
    MemberBean memberBean = (MemberBean)((HttpSession)arg0.getExternalContext().getSession(true)).getAttribute("memberBean");
    }
}
```

The method is being called by p:picklist in an ajax call but the problem is that the memberbean is null in an ajax request. The memberbean in not null if it is called during simple http request. How can i make sure that the memberbean is not null if it is called in an ajax request.

### EDITS BELOW

```
<p:dialog header="Member Contacts" widgetVar="dialog_memberContacts" resizable="false"  
                showEffect="bounce" hideEffect="explode" modal="true" position="center" appendToBody="true">
    <h:form id="form_compose_2">
            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                <p:selectOneMenu id="dropdown_groups" value="#{groupBean.selectionGroup}" converter="groupConverter"
                    style="size:200px;">  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Group" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{groupBean.groups}" var="group" itemLabel="#{group.gname}" itemValue="#{group}"/>  
                    <p:ajax process=":form_compose_2:list_members" update=":form_compose_2" listener="#{groupBean.handleGroupChange}" />  
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:pickList id="list_members" value="#{membershipBean.membersList}" var="member" 
                        iconOnly="true" itemLabel="#{member.fname} #{member.lname}" style="width:450px;"
                        itemValue="#{member}" converter="memberConverter">  
                    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Available</f:facet>  
                    <f:facet name="targetCaption">Selected</f:facet>  
                </p:pickList>

            <p:commandButton value="Ok" action="#{groupBean.updateMemberState}" oncomplete="dialog_memberContacts.hide()"
                    update=":form_compose:input_group" style="float:right;"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

Is it to do with the dialog. There are two forms on this page. One is within the dialog as you can see. The other form is form_compose

Comment: `memberBean` will not be `null` if it is in session scope irrespective of type of request (ajax or otherwise). Make sure you are putting your bean in session at the right time and fetching it with right name.

Comment: I am sure that memberBean has been created before the ajax request as I am accessing it in other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to get it from the `HttpSession`, I think you should annotate your `Converter` with `@MangagedBean` and `@RequestScope` and inject your `@SessionScoped` bean with `@ManagedProperty`. It would be something like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MemberConverter extends Converter {
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{memberBean}")
    private MemberBean memberBean;

    ...
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Comment: Thanks J4mes. This approach work but I was hesitent to use to but it seem this is the only approch that work.